# Schema design for top ranked post query in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, database-schema

I have requirement where I need to find top ranked pictures in chronological order from certain city. I came up with below schema

```
create table top_picture(
    picture_id uuid,
    city text,
    rank int,
    date timestamp,
    primary key (city,date,rank)
) with CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date desc,rank desc);
```

It does solve problem to some extent (apart from duplicates) by executing following query

```
select * from top_picture where city='san diego';
```

. But if same picture_id is inserted in same day then I get duplicate entries as  picture_id is not part of partition key. However I can not add it to partitioning key because then I won't be able make simple selection query like above as I would need to provide picture_id with selection query and it won't give top pics for city.

Did anyone came accross this type of schema before or any other recommended ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want two views of the data.  In one view you want to get the top ranked pictures and in the other view you want the picture_id to be unique.

So you could have two tables, with one that has picture_id as the primary key and the other as you have shown.

When you have a picture to insert, you would first try to insert it into the picture_id table using the IF NOT EXISTS clause on the insert statement.  If that insert fails, then it is a duplicate and you would not insert it into the top_picture table.

In Cassandra 3.0 there is going to be support for materialized views like this, but for now you would have to manage both tables in your application code.

Comment: The purpose of top_picture table is to store the ranks for pictures as other users ranks it. Say user A and B ranks the same picture_id xx on same day d1 then it will have 2 entries in above table, and one more problem is  if i have the same situation in day d2 then i hav e4 entries unless I do read and update. I was trying build it as immutable store to find top picture.

Comment: You should probably clarify that in the question.  I don't understand how your ranking system works.  Are they like votes that get added up?

Comment: Yes its like as user rates it  rank is incremented by 1.